# Problem when I place javascript in $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am having following code working fine when placed without $(document).ready

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_FirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_LastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="txtSubmit" Text="Validate" runat="server" />
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="AtLeastOneTextBoxValidator" runat="server" 
        ClientValidationFunction="Validate_Textbox" ValidateEmptyText="true">
 </asp:CustomValidator>


function Validate_Textbox(sender, args) {
        var firstName = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox_FirstName.ClientID %>");
        var lastName= document.getElementById("<%= TextBox_LastName.ClientID%>");
        if ((firstName == "") && (lastName == "")){
              window.alert("Error");
        }
}
```

When I placed this code inside $(document).ready it is giving '**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected'** error.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    function Validate_Textbox(sender, args) {
        var firstName = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox_FirstName.ClientID %>");
        var lastName = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox_LastName.ClientID%>");
        if ((firstName == "") && (lastName == "")){
              window.alert("Error");
        }
    }       
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're treating `<%= TextBox_LastName.ClientID%>` as a string, rather than getting it's value from, I'm going to guess, ASP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're now declaring the `Validate_Textbox` function inside another (anonymous) function. Like all variables, it is now usable only inside that function. You won't be able to use it anywhere else in your application.

There's no functional advantage to declaring functions inside a `$(document).ready()` callback. The better question is: where is `Validate_Textbox` **called**?

Comment: I am using Validate_Textbox in CustomValidator <asp:CustomValidator ID="AtLeastOneTextBoxValidator" runat="server" 
        ClientValidationFunction="Validate_Textbox" ValidateEmptyText="true">

Answer (score 3):

That's happening because something's looking for your `Validate_Textbox` function which is not defined *only* in that `document.ready` handler's scope, not globally...so outside that `document.ready` handler, `Validate_Textbox` doesn't exist...when you call it, you get your error.

Answer (score 2):

You should have this outside of the $(document).ready block as it is a self contained function and will be called from code within the $(document).ready block.